# Раскраска datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Есть два связанных datagridview

```
 public void LoadData()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conparms);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand objCmd = new MySqlCommand(" SELECT график.id_графика, Врач.фамилия,Врач.имя, Врач.отчество, специальность.название, график.дата,график.время FROM Врач INNER JOIN специальность ON Врач.спец = специальность.id_спец INNER JOIN график ON график.врач = Врач.id_врача", conn); 


        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(objCmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        MySqlConnection conn1 = new MySqlConnection(conparms);
        conn1.Open();
        MySqlCommand objCmd1 = new MySqlCommand("  SELECT пациент.фамилия, пациент.имя, пациент.отчество, запись.id_записи, запись.график FROM запись INNER JOIN пациент  ON запись.пациент = пациент.id_пациента;", conn1);


        MySqlDataAdapter adp1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(objCmd1);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        adp1.Fill(dt1);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
```

//связывание двух таблиц
            DataSet ds;

```
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

       ds.Relations.Add("myRelation", ds.Tables["table1"].Columns["id_графика"], ds.Tables["table2"].Columns["график"]);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;

        dataGridView1.DataMember = "table1";
        dataGridView2.DataMember = "table1.myRelation";
    }
```

Необходимо реализовать в первой таблицы цветовую раскраску строк.
Например: Если во второй таблицы нет записи, которая соответствует первой, то строка окрашивается в зеленый (запись открыта).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если во второй таблице есть запись, которая соответствует первой, то строка окрашивается в красный ( запись закрыта).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть нужно сделать третью невидимую таблицу с запросом

```
SELECT запись.график, запись.id_записи FROM запись;
```

Помогите, пожалуйста :(

Comment: Вы бы написали код ручного заполнения двух DataTable, чтобы каждый желающий помочь мог его скопировать, вставить себе и запустить. Тогда бы вам быстро ответили.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov так весь код представлен

Comment: И? Разве могу я его скопировать и запустить? У меня есть заполненная вашими данными БД?

Comment: могу выдать доступ

Comment: Угу, нужно будет ставить мускуль... Ради ответа на форуме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подписываем первый грид на событие RowPrePaint.

```
private void DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    var row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    if (row.DataBoundItem == null)
        return;

    var rowView = (DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem;
    var dataRow = rowView.Row;

    if (dataRow.GetChildRows("myRelation").Length > 0)
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Полный пример приложения. Данные в DataTable заносятся вручную.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView1;
        DataGridView dataGridView2;

        public Form1()
        {
            var dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("id_графика", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

            var dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("график", typeof(int));

            dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Суханова");
            dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Суханова");
            dt1.Rows.Add(3, "Суханова");

            dt2.Rows.Add("Каплин", 1);
            dt2.Rows.Add("Ба", 2);
            dt2.Rows.Add("Бо", 2);

            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
            ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

            ds.Relations.Add("myRelation", ds.Tables["table1"].Columns["id_графика"], ds.Tables["table2"].Columns["график"]);


            Size = new Size(500, 500);
            dataGridView1 = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            dataGridView2 = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;

            dataGridView1.DataMember = "table1";
            dataGridView2.DataMember = "table1.myRelation";

            dataGridView1.RowPrePaint += DataGridView1_RowPrePaint;
        }

        private void DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            if (row.DataBoundItem == null)
                return;

            var rowView = (DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem;
            var dataRow = rowView.Row;

            if (dataRow.GetChildRows("myRelation").Length > 0)
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            else
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо с: 
Вы лучший♥